# Change root name in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, command-line, root, username

how're you doing? I am somewhat new to ubuntu and finding problem changing the root user name. My terminal displays priyank@Alex right now. I changed the second name to Alex using hostname and hosts. What I want is to make it Alex@Alex. Can anyone temme how can I do it?

Comment: This is a duplicate, the system should automatically include that in a reply. It's a little complicated but not too bad. Follow the example in the highest rated answer and if you have trouble with that then ask a specific question and we'll help you out from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just two steps:

> 1.edit the /etc/passwd file ,replace `priyank` to `Alex` ,then save
>
> 2.edit the /etc/shadow file ,replace `priyank` to `Alex`,then save

reboot and enjoy it

Answer (score 1):

Use usermod command ideally - -l is the option you're after in this particular case. If you want also your home dir renamed accordingly - options -d and -m may be of your interest.