# How to change "root" name in a remote ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, root, user-management, username

I would like to change the "root" name to a custom name in a remote ubuntu 20.4 machine.
I tried the solution from [Change root name in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693279/change-root-name-in-ubuntu) but it doesnt work. Now I cannot log in at all.

I also checked this solution [Renaming user name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558669/renaming-user-name) but the machine runs on a GUI.

What is the correct process to change the name from "root" to lets say "user1"?

Note: Please double check before marking question as "duplicate". The links mentioned are not a clear answer to the question.

Comment: [This U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8453) might help you in your quest 

Comment: Not a good idea. You don't want this. The root account, moreover, is not enabled in a default Ubuntu install. Log in as a user that has sudo privileges instead.